# fatal: Authentication failed for

Tags: git, github

I have truble doing my first commit

i'm currently following git instruction :

```
echo "# my_Ohmyfood" >> README.md
git init
git add README.md
git commit -m "first commit"
git branch -M main
git remote add origin https://github.com/MargYre/my_Ohmyfood.git
git push -u origin main
```

But at the last command, my Username and Password are ask, then I got the following:

```
error: unable to read askpass response from '/usr/libexec/openssh/gnome-ssh-askpass'
```

and

```
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/MargYre/my_Ohmyfood.git/'
```

I must had this is my portable pc, and i have no problem with my fix one. Even thought I have had ssh key on both pc on my github account

Answer (score 0):

SSH should not be involved with an HTTPS URL.

Try first:

```
unset SSH_ASKPASS
```

And push again.
It might have been set by `/etc/profile.d/gnome-ssh-askpass.sh`.

On Linux, install the [Git Credential Manager](https://github.com/GitCredentialManager/git-credential-manager#linux) and, if you have a graphical user interface session, [`servetservice`](https://github.com/GitCredentialManager/git-credential-manager/blob/main/docs/credstores.md#freedesktoporg-secret-service-api).
That will cache your credentials HTTPS, which should be:

- your GitHub user account
- your GitHub PAT ([Personal Access Token](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token))